# Extending border in tabular environment

Tags: tables, multicolumn

For the  back-to-back stem-and-leaf plot below, how would you modify the code so that the highlighted bit comes through?
For some strange reason, this is missing when I compile latex.

[image: current output]

Thanks

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{lllll|c|lllllll}
\multicolumn{5}{r}{\textbf{Town 1}} & \textbf{Stem} & \multicolumn{6
}{l}{\textbf{Town 2}}\\[0.024cm]\hline
  & 7 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 9 &   &\\[0.124cm]
  & 8 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 8 & 9\\[0.124cm]
8 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 4 & 6 & 7 &   & \\[0.124cm]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\multicolumn{5}{r|}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `{r|}` instead of `{r}` you can add the missing part of the vertical line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{lllll|c|lllllll}
\multicolumn{5}{r|}{\textbf{Town 1}} & \textbf{Stem} & \multicolumn{6
}{l}{\textbf{Town 2}}\\[0.024cm]\hline
  & 7 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 9 &   &\\[0.124cm]
  & 8 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 8 & 9\\[0.124cm]
8 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 4 & 6 & 7 &   & \\[0.124cm]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you @leandriis!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` instead of `{tabular}`, you will have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]

\begin{NiceTabular}{lllll|c|llllll}
\multicolumn{5}{r}{\textbf{Town 1}} & \textbf{Stem} & \multicolumn{6
}{l}{\textbf{Town 2}}\\[0.024cm]\hline
  & 7 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 9 &   &\\[0.124cm]
  & 8 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 8 & 9\\[0.124cm]
8 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 4 & 6 & 7 &   & \\[0.124cm]
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]